# Moving div due to navbar content from above

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to make navigation tabs on my page. Currently I have a two nav bars within one `div. They work fine. However, when I panel through the tabs, the content changes height causing the nav bar below it to move up and down. How do I stop that from happening?

The configurations div is on top of the Mobile div within the same div

ex:

```
  <div>
    <div class="config"></div>
    <div class="mobile" style="position:inherit;"></div>
  <div>
```

#### Before

[image: before]

#### After

[image: After]

Also as you can see the nav bar lines do not line up as the Mobile line is shorter than the configurations nav bar line. How can I adjust this?

Comment: You need much more code than this for us to be able to help you.  Can you include the full HTML/CSS?

Comment: @JoshBurgess the full html is pretty big =/

Comment: Well, pop it in a jsFiddle and post the link.  Without seeing the HTML, it's really hard to tell what's going on.  The CSS is going to play an important role too.  Narrow it down to the smallest bit you can to recreate the problem, and you'll get plenty of responses.

Comment: update in the codepen or jsfiddle and provide the link here

Comment: The alignment is pretty bad for the tiny box http://jsfiddle.net/liondancer/ccvfnd8t/1/

Comment: That's fine.  The size of the viewport shouldn't matter if it's done right.  It's going to be bad because something is wrong with your CSS/HTML.

Comment: @JoshBurgess everything works for me it's just the bottom mobile div moves up and down due to the top div content adjusting in size =/

Comment: @JoshBurgess and bootstrap's nav line being too short haha I think it is a margin issue? or some spacing property. I'm new to front end dev =[

Comment: I still can't tell what it is that you're asking for.  It moves up and down how?  Is this a stacking issue?  You want the first box to stay the same size when the tab is switched?

Comment: i think you missed out some js here?? i am not sure. because i am not getting any up down movement  though:) just asking???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is what you're asking, but here goes:

## Preventing content from moving subsequent divs

You have a container div which houses both child divs.  You want both to display within the context of the container, but you don't want each to move the position of the other.

Here's how you do that:

```css
.container {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
}
.container div {
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-panel-1" style="background-color:blue; color:white;">
    <ul>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content-panel-2" style="background-color:red; color:white;">
    <ul>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
      <li>A whole bunch of content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

## As a side note:

If you want to help your alignment, this little bit of CSS should immensely improve your list layouts:

```
 ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
 }
```